# Pandas - Compare 2 columns in a dataframe and return count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

DataFrame:

[image]

I want to compare these 2 columns and extract the count of matched and un matched rows.

result will be like

```
Matched = 3
Un matched = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare values first by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and count by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html), then replace `True, False` indices:

```
s = (df.input_number.eq(df.org_number)
                    .value_counts()
                    .rename({True:'mach', False: 'no match'}))
```

If need DataFrame:

```
sdf1 = (df.input_number.eq(df.org_number)
                       .value_counts()
                       .rename({True:'mach', False: 'no match'})
                       .rename_axis('state')
                       .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'input_number':[123,253,458,479,1564],'org_number':[1234,253,458,478,1564]})
matched, un_matched = df[df['input_number']==df['org_number']].shape[0],df[df['input_number']!=df['org_number']].shape[0]
print("Matched = {}\nUn matched = {}".format(matched,un_matched))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way, boolean index, conditionally allocate match status. Thereafter get_summies and sum down the columns. Code below

```
pd.get_dummies(np.where(df['code_207']==df['code_207a'],'matched','unmatched')).sum(0)
```